# My code does not work: Prime Number between Intervals JAVA

Tags: java

currently working on some tasks for learning purposes on Programiz.
Can someone help me with the correction of the code? thanks a lot <3 This is the task:

> *Prime Numbers Between Intervals
>
> Hard
>
> Problem Description
>
> Create a method to find all the prime numbers between two intervals using a method.
>
> Step 1:
>
> Create a method named checkPrime() with an integer parameter, number.
> Inside the method, check if the number is prime or not. If the number is prime, return true. Otherwise, return false.
>
> Step 2:
>
> Inside main(), get integer inputs for two intervals x and y, such that y should be greater than x.   Run a loop to access each number between x and y. Call checkPrime() with each value between the intervals.
> If the returned value is true, print the number.*

**This is the code by me, which does not work (Issue: does not print the Prime Numbers):**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    // method to check prime number
    // return true if the number is prime, else return false
    // hint: Use the same logic from the previous challenge

    boolean checkPrime(int number){
        boolean flag = true;
        
        for (int i = 2; i <= (number - 1); i++){
            if (number % i == 0){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
         return flag;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // get input value for two intervals
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();

        Main obj = new Main();

        // run a loop to access each value in interval x and y
        for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i) {

            // call checkPrime for every value between x and y
           boolean result = obj.checkPrime(x, y);

            // if returned value is true, print the number
            if (true) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

this is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Well, your `checkPrime` method only takes one argument...

Comment: Also `if (true) {` should be `if (result)`. The way you wrote it basically means "always".

Comment: By the way, you probably meant to pass `i` to `checkPrime`.

Comment: 1 - you do not need to add this else statement : ```else {flag = true;}```

2 - ```checkPrime``` accept only one param, you are passign two..

Answer (score 1):

this is a compile-time error only,
calling checkprime method inside the main function

```
// call checkPrime for every value between x and y
          boolean result = obj.checkPrime(x, y);
```

checkPrime method only takes one parameter but here you passed two parameters.

```
boolean checkPrime(int number){
```

that is why you are getting the error.
passing only one parameter will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

// Replace ___ with your code
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

```
// method to check prime number
// return true if the number is prime, else return false
// hint: Use the same logic from the previous challenge
boolean checkPrime(int number){
    boolean flag = true;
   
    
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= (number - 1); i++){
        if (number % i == 0){
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
     return flag;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // get input value for two intervals
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int y = input.nextInt();

    Main obj = new Main();

    // run a loop to access each value in interval x and y
    for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i) {

        // call checkPrime for every value between x and y
       boolean result = obj.checkPrime(i);

        // if returned value is true, print the number
        if (result) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        }
         input.close(); 
    }
```

}